# Was Christianity legalized during the Meiji Restoration?

Tags: meiji-restoration

Also were men given the right to vote during the Restoration?

Comment: Don't the title and the question body refer to different things?

Comment: He could have made them two different questions.

Answer (score 5):

After the Meiji-Restoration, Christianity, and all religions were legalized, and according to the article I read, were "promulgated."

In 1890, after the Restoration, the wealthiest men (about 1% of the population), were allowed to vote for parliament. By 1925, all men were allowed.

http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2298.html 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_Japan#Christianity

http://afe.easia.columbia.edu/special/japan_1750_meiji.htm (See social and economic changes)